# Cannot get window[function] to work correctly

Tags: javascript, string, function

I have a string that varies from page to page carrying the functions it needs to be executed once a user signs in. I have everything working up to the point of executing multiple functions. I use these two functions:

```
function callback(wrapper)
{
    if (secFn == "") {}
    else {
        if (doopitydoo >= nAccess) {
            var secAr = secFn.split('&');
            secAr.forEach(exFn);
        }
        else {
            window.location = 'http://homepage';
        }
    }
}

function exFn(item, index) {
    window[item]();
}
```

The variables `doopitydoo`, `nAccess`, and `secFn` are defined earlier in a different script. `doopitydoo` is one's security access and `nAccess` is the required access for the page; there is no problem there. But `secFn` is a string that contains multiple functions. For example, if it contains "`funA`&`funB`&`funC`", the code splits the functions into `secAr` by the `&` symbol.

I have used alerts to see when the functions are running the first function, and I've noticed that while "`funA`" always runs, but the second two do not. If I change the `exFn` function to be just an alert with the function name instead of actually executing the function, they all fire. It is only when the actual functions try to be executed is where is fails (i.e. `window[item]();`).

Does anyone have any idea as to why this is happening? I am writing this in a rush, so please forgive any typos or any parts of the code that I forgot to explain. Also, I have tried to change the `foreach` into a regular for loop, but with the same results.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what exactly do you mean by "is where it fails"? Is there a specific error that it's giving you, or is it just hanging? (If it's the latter, maybe your functions are simply taking a long time to execute?)

Comment: I can't reproduce this, using Firefox Nightly with the following code: `window.test1 = () => console.log('foo!'); window.test2 = () => console.log('bar!'); window.test3 = () => console.log('baz!'); ['test1', 'test2', 'test3'].forEach(fn => window[fn]());`. I get all three strings logged to the console, as expected.

Comment: Because of you, I changed my first function to just a console.log and now it works. Thanks for your help! I will try to get my function working now... @BalinKingOfMoria

Comment: Awesome! In that case, the functions themselves might be throwing errors, hanging (and blocking execution), etc.... Are there any errors in your web browser's console when you try to run your original code? (Also, you can try to break on exceptions if you really want to know if (and/or where) your functions are throwing errors; how to do this probably depends on your specific browser.)

Comment: I fixed it! I was a complete idiot and had a wrong variable being compared. I was not using the global one, but my local one for a different function I was working on recently. (They have the same content, but the local one was throwing the error) @BalinKingOfMoria

Comment: Glad you got it working!